How do I detect if the user goes back or forward through the history in the current tab?
I'm going to implement a simple web extension for my personal needs (currently for Chrome, but I consider moving to Firefox and abandon the former), and this extension only requires the history and tabs permissions. What I'm looking for is a way to detect if I move forward or back within the current tab.
In short, I want to build a stack per tab, and push an element to it or pop an element from it on moving forward (including navigation to a non-history element that's also considered a move forward) or back respectively.
From what I've seen in the documentation for both Chrome and Firefox, the closest methods and events I could find are the following:

chrome.tabs.goForward and chrome.tabs.goBack: these are just methods, not events, but trigger the below events;
chrome.history.onVisited: an event, provides neither the direction, back or forward, nor the tab ID;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated: the event that seems to be the most relevant to what I'm looking for, it also provides both status: "loading" and url via the changeInfo callback parameter, but still there doesn't seem any flag that indicates the direction.

None of them do exactly what I want. Is there any way to detect the direction?
The extension is planned to use Manifest v3 if it matters but I'm really okay to use Manifest v2 and Firefox.

Use chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated in the background script.

@woxxom Thanks for pointing out webNavigation. The closest events are probably onCompleted and onHistoryStateUpdated since they are triggered whenever the URL/history changes providing aux frame information and, the most important, the tabId. However, I cannot figure out how I can distinguish between navigating back and forward: whenever I navigate, say with Alt-Left and Alt-Right, I can see one of them gets triggered, and this is fine. But how do I distinguish between back and forward? I thought the documentId or transitionQualifier/...Type property is supposed to be the key.

Consider the following scenario. I have a service worker that's listening to those events and merely dump the documentId to the service worker console. Now I open a new tab, open example.com/ and then example.com/?foo=bar: two distinct document IDs are dumped. Seems fine. Now I go back, the third document ID gets dumped (not the first one I initially expected), and then I go forward, and I get the fourth distinct document ID (not the second one). What am I confused with and what am I missing?

The only reliable solution is Chrome's navigation.onnavigate event and its destination.index.

@woxxom Thanks for reopening the question. Your suggestion for window.navigation.addEventListener('navigate') and e.destination.index is exactly what I need to detect the history navigation direction. Could you please post your comment as the answer?

I think it'd be better if you post the actual code.

@woxxom Sorry, I don't have the original non-working code anymore in the Git repository, and its reflog is also cleared. Since I posted some thoughts on chrome.tabs and chrome.history only not providing any code but clarifying the details in the comments, I guess a few words in the answer pointing out the window.navigation and its navigate event that contains the destination index to be messaged from the page to the service worker would be just fine.
